# Is it possible to run a Python GUI on Google Chrome? If yes, please let me know how?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, google-chrome, user-interface

I have a Python file that is made with Tkinter and is a GUI. Is it possible to run that file or script on Google Chrome? How ?!

Ps: I mean to Run it like HTML which can be run directly on Google Chrome is that possible also with PY files?

Comment: Well, no. It isn't possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to run a python file in Google Chrome itself, but there is a way to run it on a Chromebook. You can turn on the Linux beta on a Chromebook and share your Python file with Linux. Check out this article: https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/9145439?hl=en
Then you can install python in the terminal with

```
sudo apt install python3
```

You can also check out this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=91OBWQexp0E

Comment: Thank you i will consider your suggestion :) i do appreciate it :)

Comment: @Danito You´re most welcome!